# Flaton theme - Theme options not saving

Tags: wordpress

I am currently building a WordPress woo-commerce store. I am using FLATON theme. The theme is premium theme not nulled. But In the dashboard Theme options tab options not working. I want to change header, footer & etc but I have changed they are not saving. After save the changes it going to 404 page. How can I fix it

Comment: try go to setting>>permalink and click on save

Comment: I have change the permalink to plain. After redirect to this page Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: change permission of your directory to 755